# Evaluate component-scoped scss styles after global min.css in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, performance, sass

### PROBLEM

Let's say we have a `min.css` file that needs to be imported globally:

index.js

```js
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "src/App";

import "library/library.min.css";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

And some `scss` styles applied on a component level:

App.js

```js
import "./styles.scss"

const App = () => (
    <div>
        {/* .. */}
    </div>
);
```

If the `scss` styles have the same level of specificity as the ones in the `min.css`, then the ones in the `min.css` will be overriding the ones coming from `scss`.

### FURTHER INFO

For adopting `scss`, I'm using the `sass` library (v1.38.2).

For comparison, you can see below how the styles are evaluated (notice the behaviour of the `background` properties between `scss` and `min.css`):

[image: scss files]

Above you can see the `min.css` overrides the `scss` styles; Below, I compiled all `scss` before runtime and in this case, the `scss` files will be overriding the `min.css` ones properly (`background-color` will override `background`):

[image: compiled css]

### CAUSE

I'd think the problem is caused because the `scss` styles are being processed first, so they get overridden by the styles on the `min.css`, even though the `min.css` is imported on `index.js` while the other `scss` are imported down the tree on the component level.

### SOLUTION

Given such supposition, I created an `index.scss` (imported on `index.js`) which contains all the app styles:

```js
@import 'library/library.min';

@import 'styles/componentStyles1';
@import 'styles/componentStyles2';
@import 'styles/componentStyles3';
..
```

And that will work, as the component styles will be overriding the minified ones.

A problem I would think of this though, is that we would be importing all styles even if we won't require them all straight up, so I'd suppose that could degrade performances (please correct me if I'm wrong).

### CONCLUSIONS

Given the above, is there any suggestion on how this could be approached in a better way? Any opinion in merit is highly welcomed, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the order of import

In, index.js

```js
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "library/library.min.css";

import App from "src/App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Can't believe it was such a banal question! That was it, thank you!

Comment: whenever I come across such issue, I just increase the specificity of selectors. This question sparkled me to find the proper solution. thank you !